# Error: Could not find module `eventsource` imported from a route

Tags: node.js, ember.js, ember-cli

I'm having some trouble importing a node module from my ember-cli app. 
In my notebook/route.js, I have

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import EventSource from 'eventsource';
```

I see other files importing other node modules like 'ember-data' this way.
However I get the following in the console when I navigate to that route:

```
Error: Could not find module `eventsource` imported from `ui/notebooks/route`
at requireFrom (loader.js:110)
at reify (loader.js:97)
at mod.state (loader.js:140)
at tryFinally (loader.js:21)
at requireModule (loader.js:139)
at Ember.DefaultResolver.extend._extractDefaultExport (ember-resolver.js:390)
at resolveOther (ember-resolver.js:122)
at superWrapper (ember.debug.js:21571)
at exports.default._emberRuntimeSystemObject.default.extend.resolveRoute (ember.debug.js:5014)
at exports.default._emberRuntimeSystemObject.default.extend.resolve (ember.debug.js:4847)
```

I installed the node module using npm install eventsource --save and it generated the following in my package.json:

```
  "devDependencies": {
"body-parser": "^1.14.1",
"broccoli-asset-rev": "^2.1.2",
"ember-cli": "1.13.8",
"ember-cli-app-version": "1.0.0",
"ember-cli-babel": "^5.1.3",
"ember-cli-dependency-checker": "^1.0.1",
"ember-cli-htmlbars": "1.0.1",
"ember-cli-htmlbars-inline-precompile": "^0.3.1",
"ember-cli-ic-ajax": "0.2.1",
"ember-cli-inject-live-reload": "^1.3.1",
"ember-cli-qunit": "^1.0.0",
"ember-cli-rails-addon": "0.0.12",
"ember-cli-release": "0.2.3",
"ember-cli-showdown": "2.5.0",
"ember-cli-sri": "^1.0.3",
"ember-cli-uglify": "^1.2.0",
"ember-data": "2.1.0",
"ember-disable-proxy-controllers": "^1.0.0",
"ember-export-application-global": "^1.0.3",
"express": "^4.13.3",
"glob": "^4.5.3",
"morgan": "^1.6.1",
"nedb": "^1.2.1"
},
"dependencies": {
  "eventsource": "^0.1.6"
}
```

It seems to be a valid node package, sourced [here](https://github.com/aslakhellesoy/eventsource-node):

Can anybody help shed some light on this?  New to ember and node but not to Javascript ... I'm a rails developer.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You can't import every npm module to Ember CLI application just because it's npm module.

You can only use import keyword with special npm packages - Ember CLI addons, which expose some public API for your application.

Comment: I see -- so since it's not in bower, do I just include it like I would any javascript vendored resource?

Comment: I think you have to create Ember CLI addon and then you can require eventsource module there. For example, see how it's done with uglify - https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli-uglify/blob/master/index.js. Line 15.

Comment: Yep, same issue with SimpleWebRTC. Solved with `ember-cli-node-assets`.